# Is it possible to bind a HTML Canvas to an ffmpeg JavaScript port to get a video file as output without a server?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video, ffmpeg-wasm

First of all, I've found this repository which has a ffmpeg JavaScript implementation:
https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm

I'm curious if I can somehow bind my canvas output and pass some frametimes to get a video output. (for example, visualize a physics object)

So far, I've set up a basic physics simulator in JS. I have a bunch of squares being rendered based on their x and y coordinates.

```js
class PhysicsObject {
  // ...
  render(canvas, ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x - this.w / 2, this.y - this.h / 2, this.w, this.h);
  }
  // ...
}

let timer = performance.now();
// ...

function draw() {
  // ...
  let now = performance.now();
  dt = (now - timer) / 1000;
  timer = now;
  // ...

  for (let object of physicsObjects) {
    // ...
    object.update(dt);
    object.render(canvas, ctx);
    // ...
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

I now need a way to link my canvas output to the ffmpeg and some other parameters but I have no idea where to even start.

If there is a way to bind the canvas output to the ffmpeg port, I'd like to delve deeper into the documentation of this ffmpegwasm thing.

Comment: Googled your own question, this came up 1st result, maybe it provides insight on to the how: https://github.com/ilufang/canvas2ffmpeg

Comment: i was talking about a completely client-sided application, thats why i chose ffmpegwasm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar request with solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863547/save-canvas-data-as-mp4-javascript) with example code. The ffmpeg.wasm code on that answer looks a little old, but the basic technique should be what you are after.

You record the canvas to a .webm video using [MediaRecorder (MDN docs with example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)) and then (optionally) use ffmpeg.wasm to transcode the .webm video to .mp4. All of it is done in the browser.

Another reference on how to record a canvas to a video file:
[How to record a canvas element](https://medium.com/@amatewasu/how-to-record-a-canvas-element-d4d0826d3591)

Answer (score 0):

You cant render in realtime because browser can lag. You must send frames via ajax and wait for response. On server side store image and add row to concat file.

Comment: I think you missed the "without a server" part of his request.

Comment: yes, imposible without server

Comment: Not at all impossible. In fact, it is quite easy using MediaRecorder as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863547/save-canvas-data-as-mp4-javascript) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).